# How to match only YouTube id from multiline string?

Tags: python, regex

How do I match only the 11 character YouTube id from each URL without getting anything else?

URLs:

```
test_string = """https://youtu.be/uJei9-tepRE
https://youtu.be/1m7czKyDatU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Disi_5W3J8I&ab_channel=AubreyHaddard
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aqhtu2HEhtU&ab_channel=ElusivityRadio
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9n62phJQnM4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntvPhgxHfRE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9Szz0a0UYM
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ExMjEwymQ3A
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9u5I9625b4&feature=emb_title
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4eCh2N4RIk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhtX3poCNOg
https://youtu.be/WAbFfFvKtvw
https://nervousdater.bandcamp.com/track/nothing-left
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UBn3ipMq_A
https://soundcloud.com/carlosvivanco-1/diminished-all-over
https://youtu.be/7XKkmQwTF_4
https://youtu.be/1G2RbPoFFOU
https://youtu.be/imMQVdshYQg
https://cigazze.bandcamp.com/track/eastwood-2
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=33heuMT2iUs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AkjyEFbsfQ4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nqEDPQR5X0&feature=emb_title
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHIaWN6mkKY
https://youtu.be/pSgXSwx3yOI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVgqHZbp-pw"""
```

Using originally:

```
regex = "[=\/]{1}\K[_a-zA-Z0-9-]{11}"
```

This regex is matching "diminished-" and a few others but I want it to only match the 11 character YouTube id from only YouTube links.

Comment: What was the problem with what you have tried?

Comment: What is `\K` supposed to mean?

Comment: @coder9741 the `\K` is literally the character `K`, if you're building regex, there are fine websites out there to live build and check them with explenations of what it's looking for and highlighting. EDIT: your current regex will trigger on other things than just the ID.

Comment: woops I was using php regex O.o ^^

Comment: Please kindly keep original attempts in question.

Comment: Why? I accidentally used php regex for my attempt, why would I post that? It just adds useless information and clutter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```py
(?:youtube\.com/watch\?v=|youtu\.be\/)([^&\n]{11})\b
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/FOoZ4H/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    youtube                  'youtube'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    com/watch                'com/watch'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \?                       '?'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    v=                       'v='
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    youtu                    'youtu'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    be                       'be'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^&\n]{11}               any character except: '&', '\n'
                             (newline) (11 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

**[Python code example](https://tio.run/##nVRhb9owEP3Or0D90ILUEEigHZVQxdpkUAQltGnpxhY5iYNdEjvYl4Sw7bezDFVtJTpF2idL99698909XZwD4Uzf7WgUcwFVgSuAJTgSBGXLaq96dHREAGJ5oao5TyBpuFhNbjDtKoDjmVE5AFvRubcd5dcI7Fcwy7LGnuDihscjNUPgkcu0d00ldTqP@s2n4TFyHY8gxnDY6yeuwPkA@T4SfqlIf00g0QYGAfu9iBEmkqYU8hnyKS9V6bIzLSY3Fhu3S7kM0ilZbgbBu/7/xYXu3XbbRE37aVzKNTbjZyPLI0vvl3LtbtIZds@0jts@DjCCROAejlwHKIS4NDto4yuiTdqz4ap8SQTmesyvJrfLw20/9l0zMNMRpNkryLBIeSJ9BFg0XMR8D0XxXhIE8lYq40AKcykhDqC0etP@zHQaj9fO20wkTwrRkCf@nuohEXKZ0hQxjyst1acRZVQS7CsoDBWeYnH48fP5aBVZ2b3ptD/w8Bdt5k65ad7ahyCNxtaDL8mT9TYPjy7Rdos/6hYjCRnnvqKV9qrrBCfje43astz1q@fcMF0ZWOV@ddjauJ5as868@R9emQyG6HFyFq1GT4fDiO@W87tso@e3w1Ih82G5Hnx1YyXOiqtSif6GsSxujMCNgDK/WFZNnNQuL16SF2/ZiyL91z68KKou1Hrt24/jBfv@s9X6XV@4J6fVd1erXomLB2ovBeq73R8)**

```py
matches = re.findall(r'(?:youtube\.com/watch\?v=|youtu\.be\/)([^&\n]{11})\b', test_string)
```

Comment: this was way cleaner than my attempt `youtu(?:be)?.(?:com|be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.{11})` very nice